# Anaconda cannot downgrade python to 3.6, and cannot install tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I want my base environment use python 3.6.10
From anaconda documentation, we can download the old version anaconda, or use `conda install python=3.6` but it ends up the solving environment.

What is solving environment for? I ended up to solving environment many times when I install packages.

```
(base) PS C:\Users\User> conda install python=3.6.10
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \
```

I downloaded the latest anaconda, and here is the conda info

```
     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\User\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\User\.condarc
          conda version : 4.8.3
    conda-build version : 3.18.11
         python version : 3.8.3.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=10.0
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3  (read only)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\User\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\User\.conda\envs
                          C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.3 requests/2.24.0 CPython/3.8.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.18362
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

-----Updates-----
So I created an environment to avoid the solving environment situation.
Now I try to install tensorflow 1.15.0 with ```So I create the environment, and try to install tenserflow 1.15.0 with command.

`conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow==1.15.0` and It ends up to solving environment again. What causing this solving environment keep happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anaconda wants to update itself and use new version of python. Usually I don't touch my base environment and just let anaconda update it. I don't install any extra packages into the base environment.

If I want to run a script that needs an old version of python, I create a new environment with that old version, and then use this new environment to run the script:

```sh
conda create --name py2 python=2.7
conda create --name py3 python=3.5
```

See [How to run anaconda2 python on anaconda3 python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64682005/how-to-run-anaconda2-python-on-anaconda3-python/64682096#64682096)

Comment: also, once you have any environment (base or not) it's best to not change the version of python. if you need a different version of python, create a new environment.

Comment: But why? I have been looking through the stack overflow. Why always recommend virtual environment? That doesn't really clear my question. It is more like working around of it.

Comment: Erh. Everyone does it this way. Unless your job is I.T. and install anaconda environment, I don't think spending too much time to look for the reason is a good idea. We can clone an environment and then modify the clone. Usually I just don't touch the base environment. When anaconda updates, it uses the base environment. It is very possible that suddenly anaconda itself want to use a new package that needs a new version of python. Then it wants to update python to update itself. So, keeping the base environment with an old version of python means no update and that is bad idea.

Comment: So I create the environment, and try to install tenserflow 1.15.0 with command.
```conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow==1.15.0``` ends up to solving environment as well... I dont think this solve the problem.

Comment: Oh. You mean to fix the messed up base environment. I would get the yaml of your base. Then either delete and reinstall conda. And then recreate a replica of your old base env as a *new* environment. Undo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54172339/conda-install-screwed-up-my-environment-can-i-undo-it Yaml: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html